# drf-yasg: Image field not displaying in swagger ui

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, swagger, drf-yasg

I am new to django-rest-framework. I am using DRF and drf-yasg Swagger. Can any body help to upload image from request body? I am not able to upload image from request body. My current view.py:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', request_body=MySerializer)
@api_view(['POST'])
def image(request):
    profile_img = request.FILES.get('profile_img', '')
    cover_img = request.FILES.get('cover_img', '')
    ...
    pass
```

my_serializer.py:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    profile_img = serializers.ImageField()
    profile_img = serializers.ImageField()
```

Can any one explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set [**`FormParser`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser) class in your view function as,

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser
from rest_framework.decorators import parser_classes


@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', request_body=MySerializer)
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes((FormParser,))
def image(request):
    profile_img = request.FILES.get('profile_img', '')
    cover_img = request.FILES.get('cover_img', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MultiPartParse` as you are using images.

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser
from rest_framework.decorators import parser_classes

@parser_classes((MultiPartParser,))
def image(request):
    profile_img = request.FILES.get('profile_img', '')
    cover_img = request.FILES.get('cover_img', '')
```